# Zend Autofill dropdown after select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have been working on a code to autofill dropdowns onchange, after selecting the required values from an autocomplete search field. The problem is that my autofill does not work after selecting the value, but the Jquery to execute the script and fetch the id works perfectly, don’t know what I’m missing. here’s a bit of my code and picture. Take note I have multiple jquery scripts executing types of programs. Here is the error message I get
`Message: Could not find row 50390`

Stack trace:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\application\modules\admin\controllers\AjaxController.php(366): Model_SicCode->getsiccode('50390'
```

Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'ajax',
  'action' => 'autofill',
  'sicid' => '50390',
  'lang' => 'en',
  'module' => 'admin',
)
```

The id does exist in my database but my dropdowns just don’t change. How can I go about this?

```
contoller

    public function autofillAction()
    {
        //get the id send via a get - the sic id
        $division= $this->getRequest()->getParam('sicid');  

        //get majorgroup name, group name and sic description
        //fill dropdowns with relevant values - new form with drop downs
        //selecting the required values same as autocomplete (don't know)
        $mdlSic = new Model_SicCode();
        $results = $mdlSic->getsiccode($division);
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $Division = $result->div_code;

            $mdlDivision = new Model_Division();
            $result = $mdlDivision->getSicViaDiv($division);
            $name = $result->div_desc;
            $id = $result->div_code;


            $mgrp_desc->addMultiOption($id, $name);
        }
        $mgrp_desc->setOrder(4);  

        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(false);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
        $ajaxContext->addActionContext('newfield', 'html')->initContext();

        $id = $this->_getParam('id', null);

        $this->view->field = $div_desc->__toString();   
    }


jquery

    function ajaxautofill(id) { 
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            url: '<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/admin/ajax/autofill/sicid/' + id,


                        //data: 'division':$('#div_desc').val(),
                        //dataType: 'JSON',
                        //async: true,
                        success: function(data) 
                        {
                            //fill drop downs

                            $('#t2').append(data);
                        }
            });
      }
```

Get siccode

```
   public function getSICviaDiv($d_id)
            {
                $select = $this->select()->where('div_code = ?', $d_id);    


                    $results = $this->fetchAll($select);
                if (count($results))
                    return $results;
                else
                    return 'nothing';
```

}

GetsicViaDiv

```
public function getSicViaDiv($siccode)
        {
            $select = $this->select();
            $select->where('div_code = ?', $siccode);

            return $this->fetchAll($select);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've built the `select` object twice. Secondly, I'd suggest the answer is here:

```
$row = $this->fetchRow($select);    
if (!$row) 
{
    throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
}
```

You're throwing an exception if the `RowSet` object returned, from `fetchRow`, is false. I'll work up some code this evening when I have my laptop handy.